# How to build libssh on windows 64 bit and visual studio 2015 ultimate?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, libssh

After successfully using cmake-gui configure and generate commands to generate nmake makefile, this error appears after running nmake command from VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt:

```
libssh/priv.h(68): fatal error C1189: #error:  "no snprintf compatible function found"
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Did Microsoft change anything regarding snprintf function ?

How to mitigate this ?

Comment: please try to open and compile solution - it must be generated by CMake

Comment: The nmake fails, as I  said. If you mean I should make vs2015 solution with cmake-gui and then open it with vs2015, it would generate similar errors.

Comment: Oh... Sorry. You are right. I've checked sources. it means that CMake doesn't see `snprintf` function from MSVS distribution. This may happen only if both macros HAVE__SNPRINTF_S and HAVE__SNPRINTF are not defined. I think that you have problems with include paths. Please attach CMake configure log here. It will help to localize problem